# favicon did not show on server side using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, html, favicon

I used the favicon like this

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
```

But it does not show when I run on localhost. I write this code in `merr.html` and I run on localhost host, it does not show. If I double click from windows explorer the icon show up. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: So, I take it you're running a server on your local machine like wamp or xampp or something or other?

Comment: It could be path issue. Also make sure that the image is .ico, not by renaming any 16x16 image :)

Comment: I used visual studio 2008. IIS server for asp.net. The file name is correct the size is 64x64

Comment: what is the path on the server (full URL) when you browse merr.html?

Comment: here is the full URL http://localhost:13180/GunaWangsaMerr/merr.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issued with clear cache the browser (firefox) then I restart the browser and the favicon showed. Thanks